# JSON API : does not work when there is a field starting with a number

Tags: cloudpebble, pebble-js

Here is one field of the JSON API from accuweather :
   data.list[i].rain.3h
It doesn't work when using Javascript (from cloudpebble). This line produces an error :
      var rain =1;
      rain = data.list[i].rain.3h;
The error is :
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: JS failed.

The problem comes from the "3" because it works for all others field. Do you know a workaround to make it work ?

PS : API description is here (not sure you need it):
http://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Answer (score 0):

Somebody gave me the solution : I can use this syntax to make it work when it starts with a digit : 
   rain=data.list[i].rain['3h']